# How to fix SQL output into two decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

I have this SELECT statement:

```
  SELECT
     t.clmUnit,
     t.clmConType,
     Count(t.clmCaseID) TotalCases,
     SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Resolved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalResolved,
     cast(SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Resolved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as decimal(18,2))/cast(Count(t.clmCaseID) as decimal(18,2))*100 as [TotalResolved %],
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Unresolved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalCaseProgressed,
    cast(SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Unresolved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as decimal(18,2))/cast(Count(t.clmCaseID)as decimal(18,2))*100 as [TotalCaseProgressed %],
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Work In Progress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalFurtherConReq,
    cast(SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Work In Progress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as decimal(18,2))/cast(Count(t.clmCaseID)as decimal(18,2))*100 as [TotalFurtherConReq %]
```

Which shows the output columns as decimal figures (eg) 62.24837411 and I know I can put this into excel and format the column as a percentage, but my question is how do I get SQL to convert it to the percentage? I have tried changing the as decimal(18,2) to as decimal (4,2) which is what I want but it just throws the math overflow error?

Comment: i think you need this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp)

Comment: Try not casting each value to `DECIMAL` but instead multiply the numerator by `1.0`, and then `CAST` the final result to `DECIMAL(5, 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS Arul Suggested, you need to use cast function on the whole column calculation.

```
  SELECT
 t.clmUnit,
 t.clmConType,
 Count(t.clmCaseID) TotalCases,
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Resolved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalResolved,
 cast(SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Resolved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))/Count(t.clmCaseID) * 100  as decimal(18,2)) as [TotalResolved %],
SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Unresolved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalCaseProgressed,
cast(SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Unresolved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))/Count(t.clmCaseID) * 100 as decimal(18,2)) as [TotalCaseProgressed %],
SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Work In Progress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalFurtherConReq,
cast(SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Work In Progress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))/Count(t.clmCaseID) * 100 as decimal(18,2)) as [TotalFurtherConReq %]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
select  convert(DECIMAL(10,2),column)
```

for precision of 2 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

You are place the `cast` in a wrong place

```
cast(SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Resolved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as decimal(18,2))/cast(Count(t.clmCaseID) as decimal(18,2))*100 as [TotalResolved %],
```

Place the `CAST` for the whole result, like the below:

```
cast(SUM(CASE WHEN t.clmOutcomeType='Resolved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/cast(Count(t.clmCaseID) as decimal(18,2))*100  as decimal(18,2)) as [TotalResolved %],
```